# "Who you said, was coming to see me this morning? " Versus "Who did you say, was coming to see me this morning?"

Tags: questions, exam-questions

I am taking classes of English Grammar. My educator and I are studying Indirect questions currently. I learnt that Indirect questions are direct questions embedded in various sentences, and they follow the same structure as declarative sentences do.
I could make sense of most of this, as I thought in the class , but when I came home and started to solve the hand out, There was this problem that I could not make any sense of. The problem was:
Which is correct?

> "Who you said, was coming to see me this morning?"

Or

> "Who did you say, was coming to see me this morning?"

When I asked this to my educator, the next day, he said that the first one is correct, and supplemented it with some weird logic, and at last said, "English is illogical sometimes , and that's what it is, we can't do anything." Just mug this structure up.
But I want to know how does it relate with grammar, and at least the grammatical term for it, so that, I can study it from a grammar book.

Comment: The comma is wrong in both sentences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a sentence the first is wrong. The second is correct except for the comma, which should be removed.

It is structured like other questions with do-support.

The first is not structured as a question.  It could be a phrase. Compare

> What do you drink?  (question with do support)

> Coke is what you drink.  (embedded phrase)

So it is grammatically correct to say:

> John is who you said was coming to see me this morning.

But normally you wouldn't phrase the idea like that but "You said John was coming..." but "I don't remember who you said was coming to see me this morning"  (for example) sounds fine.

Comment: "John is who you said was coming to see me this morning" is a little unusual, but "I don't remember who you said was coming to see me this morning" sounds fine.